# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'PosixPath' and 'dict'

Tags: gradio

Im getting this error on using Gradio-client to call the Video-LLava demo api

this is my code:
import gradio as gr
import gradio_client

from gradio_client import Client
client = Client("https://languagebind-video-llava.hf.space/")
result = client.predict(

```
            {'image':"/Users/kamakshiramamurthy/Desktop/GSoC/ol_json/pic.png"},
            {'video': '/Users/kamakshiramamurthy/Desktop/GSoC/2016-01-01_0100_UK_KCET_BBC_World_News_America_218.99-223.26_ago.mp4'},       # str (filepath or URL to file) in 'Input Video' Video component
            "Describe the video",   # str in 'parameter_0' Textbox component
            fn_index=3
```

)
#print(result)